# Squid as proxy is only allowing https traffic

Tags: iptables, squid, dansguardian

I have installed Squid with Dansguardian and configured it exactly as instructed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DansGuardian). It works fine for https traffic, which is allowed through just fine. However, squid doesn't allow any http traffic through. Instead, the browser displays a page generated by squid that states that I am not allowed to access the requested resource.

What I want is squid to allow all traffic through. It is not a firewall; it is there simply to allow dansguardian to do its work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, configuring squid using the "transparent" setting on the http_port directive breaks things in squid. I removed the "transparent" keyword and it works now.